# Platformio-IDE-Terminal can't run conda, but usual terminal can

Tags: atom-editor, platformio, elementary-os

In Atom Platformio-IDE-Terminal I'm trying to set the environment but it shows this error

```
> `ERROR: The install method you used for conda--probably either `pip
> install conda` or `easy_install conda`--is not compatible with using
> conda as an application. If your intention is to install conda as a
> standalone application, currently supported install methods include
> the Anaconda installer and the miniconda installer.  You can download
> the miniconda installer from https://conda.io/miniconda.html.`
```

Usual terminal working perfectly, what is the problem?

Comment: Before you're questioning the error message, have you tried it suggests?

Comment: Yes, I went through the installation and nothing changes